# Is there any configure file read/write C code generator?

Tags: c, linux, bison, flex-lexer

I know how to generate a C scanner code with flex or bison, but unluckily, I need a C code to read && -write- configure file, but I can not generate such code with flex or bison, May be I can use configure file read/write library, but I think it's not flexible when I want custom the format of configure file, so any tips?

Comment: There are libraries for managing configuration files.  One such library is [`libconfig`](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/).  I've not used it, but it looks like it can handle quite a lot.  Another is [`libini`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/), which parses `.ini`-style configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no such dedicated tool for that, simply because it's not really that hard a job.

The reason you have lexical and semantic analysis on input is because you have to turn something *complex* (free form text with the possibility of errors) into something simple (in-memory representation with no errors).

Going the other way is usually much simpler because you can simply step through your in-memory structures and output their string representations. A simplified example, let's say your config file has the line:

```
define xyzzy integer size 5 is 1 3 5 7 9 ;
```

to create an array called `xyzzy` with five elements.

On input, you have to tokenise (lexical analysis) the character stream into something like:

```
keyword:define
name:xyzzy
keyword:integer
keyword:size
constant:5
keyword:is
constant:1
constant:3
constant:5
constant:7
constant:9
keyword:semicolon
```

and then use semantic analysis to get that into a form you can use within your program, such as a structure:

```
type = array
name = xyzzy
underlyingtype = integer
size = 5
element[1..5] = {1,3,5,7,9}
```

Now, to get that back *out* to the configuration file is relatively easy. You just walk through all your in-memory structure, such as with:

```
for each in-memory-thing imt:
    if imt.type is array:
        output "define ", imt.name, " ", imt.underlyingtype
        output " size ", imt.size, " is "
        for i = 1 to imt.size inclusive:
            output imt.element[i], " "
        output " ;" with newline
    fi
    // Handle other types of imt here
rof
```

So you can see that the act of writing to a configuration file is a lot easier than reding from it.